# Why use template engine in playframework 2 (scala) if we may stay with pure scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, template-engine

Why use scala `template-engine` in playframework 2 (scala) if we may stay with just `scala`.

Using template engine is:

- additional processor time transforming template syntax into scala code
- then compiling this code (which is not so concise as it if write it by hand - then it compiles even slower)
- Also if template is not converted yet into scala you can see that code inconsistency (red highlighting in your IDE) from you main code -
  so you should every time think about it..

Why not just use core xml/html support what `scala` provides like here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/131

Is there any pure scala template (you can recommend) I can use in `play-framework` or alone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this fits
as an answer, for last question at least.

This just scala. Just XML built-in magic.

http://www.alvarocarrasco.com/2011/03/play-framework-and-templating-with.html?m=1

Sample:

**This is a template**: Templates.scala file

```
package templates

import play.api.templates.Html
import scala.xml.Xhtml
import controllers.routes

object Main {

  def page (title:String="Default title")(content: => scala.xml.Elem) = Html {
    "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
      Xhtml.toXhtml(
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>{title}</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href={routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css").toString()} />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href={routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png").toString()} />
            <script src={routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js").toString()} type="text/javascript" />
          </head>
          <body>
            {content}
          </body>
        </html>
      )
  }

  // a panel template, just as an example
  def panel (label:String="Some label")(content: => scala.xml.Elem) = {
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-label">{label}</div>
      <div>{content}</div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

**This is an index page** index.scala file

```
package views

import templates.Main._

object IndexPage {

  def apply() = {

    page(title="Welcome to my Page!") {

      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>

        <p>Some template markup</p>

        {
          panel(label="Dashboard panel")(
            <div>
              Panel content
            </div>
          )
        }

      </div>
    }
  }

}
```

**This is a controller:** Application.scala file

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(

      views.IndexPage()

    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should ask this question to the dev team, however consider few points:

- Actually you don't need to use the Play's templating engine at all, you can easily return any string with `Ok()` method, so according to your link you can just do something like `Ok(theDate("John Doe").toString())`
- Play uses approach which is very typical for other `MVC` web-frameworks, where views are HTML based files, because... it's web dedicated framework. I can't see nothing wrong about this, sometimes I'm working with other languages/frameworks and can see that only difference in views between them is just a language-specific syntax, that's the goal!
- Don't also forget, that Play is bilingual system, someone could ask '*why don't use some Java lib for processing the views?*'
- The built-in Scala XML literals are not well-suited for creating complex programs, you easily run into issues (that's also why there's a library called [anti-xml](http://anti-xml.org/)); Martin Odersky himself regretted making this a language feature
- Finally, there are IDEs with support for Play 2 views, I'm working on Idea 12 with Play2 support and although it's not perfect (it's quite new, so sometimes there are small problems) in most cases it works fine. It understands Play view's syntax, offers autocomplete, even you can use option+click on some object in the view to jump directly to the method/model's declaration, etc.

Answering to your last question, AFAIK officially there is [Groovy engine available](http://www.playmodules.net/module/play2-groovy-templates) as a module, which offers template engine known from Play 1.x, however, keep in mind it's just a bridge for people migrating from Play 1.x to Play 2.x as it's just slower than *native* engine of Play 2.

Comment: Nice summary, might add that Scala's XML literals are not very useful for creating complex programs and Martin Odersky himself considers them a mistake in hindsight.

Comment: @MariusSoutier good point as well, could you add this to my answer?

Comment: There is one suggestion I've got:https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags

(I would use google group [sometime I use / repost there issues], but it is not so cool as stackoverflow.)

Comment: @ses: I tried to convince Play's community to start new StackExchange site dedicated for Play, with no luck, pity ;)

Comment: @MariusSoutier Just interesting to look at Martin Odersky post about it. Do you have it? why he believes that it is not good for complex things and what is that "complex". Whether template mechanism considering complex stuff to apply XML literals for ? (see the example in my answer)